# Center icon inside ul li a

Tags: css

I am styling a ul so that I can make a menu that sits on the left side. They will basically be square boxes with icons (using ionicons). The only problem I run into is, I can't get a perfect square and cannot center the icons. Here is what I have now.

```
.menu_simple ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    width:185px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 60px;
}
.menu_simple ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 10.5px 60px;
    background-color: #F0541E;
    display:block; width: 120px; height: 120px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.menu_simple ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}

.menu_simple ul li a:hover, .menu_simple ul li .current {
    color: white;
    background-color: #d84b1b
;
}
```

Also, the html I am currently using looks is this:

```
    <div class="menu_simple">
        <ul>
            <li><i class="ion-ios-person-outline" style="color:#FFFFFF;" href="#"></i></li>
            <li><a class="ion-ios-baseball-outline" style="color:#FFFFFF;" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="ion-ios-calendar-outline" style="color:#FFFFFF;" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="ion-ios-plus" style="color:#FFFFFF;" href="#"></a></li>
            <li><a class="ion-log-out" style="color:#FFFFFF;" href="#">a</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

It currently looks like this:

[image]

Comment: use `text-align:center` on `.menu_simple ul li a`

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser and select that specific element in the HTML. You should be able to see what the CSS is on that element and you'll be able to change CSS on the fly to see what your issue is. If you're using Chrome, just right-click the element and select "Inspect Element" to get to the dev tools. I think it's pretty much the same in Firefox and Safari.

Comment: @FarzadYZ thanks, that definitely helped.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for this tip, as a beginner, I wasn't aware you could see your changes live. I will definitely be using this!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. After a little research, this ended up working for me:

```
.menu_simple ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 100px 0 0 0;
    width:185px;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: fixed;
    font-size: 60px;
}

.menu_simple ul li a {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  background-color: #F0541E;
  display: block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have removed it with a normalize.css reset or something similar you will need to set padding and margin to zero for your li's in your css. By default li elements in an unordered or ordered list get some left margin to set them apart from their parent ul.